# Why does tabIndex not work after first tab to select li?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, tabindex

You can view my app here: https://moon.holdings

Here is the repo: https://github.com/Futuratum/moon.holdings

---

If you select the [ + ] Add Asset button, click in the search input and hit tab there are 2 issues.

1. Nothing is selected the first time, you have to tab again in order to select the first asset.
2. And more importantly after Bitcoin is selected, tabbing does not select the next item in the list. Instead after 4 tabs the I can see that the Coinbase button was selected instead of another li.

Here you can see that each `li` does correctly have a `tabindex`:

[image]

[image]

- 1st tab, nothing selected
- 2nd tab, Bitcoin selected
- 3rd tab, nothing selected
- 4th tab, Coinbase button selected:

[image]

The JSX of the searchModal.js component:

```
render() {
  const { assets } = this.state;

  return (
    <section id="search-modal">
      <header className="search-header">
        <input
          id="coin-search"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search"
          onChange={() => this.handleChange()}
        />
        <button className="close-modal-x" onClick={this.closeSquareEdit} />
      </header>

      <ul id="coins-list">
        { assets !== 'undefined'
          ? assets.map((asset, i) => (
            <li
              key={asset.currency}
              role="button"
              tabIndex={i}
              onFocus={() => this.setFocus(asset)}
              onBlur={this.onBlur}
              onClick={() => this.handleSelect(asset)}
            >
              {asset.name}
              <span className="symbol">{asset.currency}</span>
            </li>))
          : <li>Loading...</li>
        }
      </ul>
    </section>
  );
}
```

The main container: Board.js

```
return (
  <div id="board">
    { this.renderPortfolio(sortedAssets) }
    { edit && this.renderSquareEdit(coin) }
    { search && this.renderSearchModal() }
    { loading && moonPortfolio && <Loading /> }
    { portfolio.length === 0 && <Welcome /> }
    <PlusButton toggleSearch={this.handleSearchButton} />
    <Affiliates />
    <Nomics />
    <Astronaut logo={isTrue} />
  </div>
);
```

The renderSearch method:

```
renderSearchModal() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Search
        handleClose={() => this.toggleSquareEdit(false, {})}
        openEdit={this.toggleSquareEdit}
      />
      <div id="overlay" onClick={this.handleSearchButton} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Finally the affiliates.js component

```
const links = [
  { name: 'coinbase', link: coinbase, h4: 'Buy Bitcoin' },
  { name: 'binance', link: binance, h4: 'Buy Altcoins' },
  { name: 'changelly', link: changelly, h4: 'Swap coins' }
];

export default () => (
  <div className="affiliates">
    <ul>
      {links.map(l => (
        <a href={l.link} key={l.name} target="_blank" rel="noopener">
          <li className={l.name}>
            <h4>{l.h4}</h4>
          </li>
        </a>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Your additional tab would be expected from the input->button elements before your next tabindex is invoked. As for your issues tabbing there, you'll continue to run into issues there between browsers as `li` isn't technically a [focusable element](https://allyjs.io/data-tables/focusable.html) even if you declare a role and add a tabindex. If it were me, I'd embed a styled anchor or button element in the li's if you want to use ul, or embed styled buttons or anchors in a `nav` tag and move on with your day. PS - If you're going to do ARIA, apply it fully :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `tabindex` doesn't work the way you think it works.

When you `select` the input and press tab, it goes to the `button` next. Which is the next focusable element. Then `ul` then first `li`, then to the `open/close button` then to `coinbase button`

Using positive `tabindex` is not encouraged either.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Keyboard-navigable_JavaScript_widgets

You should be fine without the tabindex property for li elements. As you could always use arrow keys to navigate the select box items.

Also check this one here: https://medium.com/@andreasmcd/creating-an-accessible-tab-component-with-react-24ed30fde86a

Which describes how to use `role` property, which can also be deployed to help control focus flow.